# Set individual onClick events in custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a custom ViewGroup in which I create a couple of custom child Views (in the java code, not xml).
Each of these childs needs to have the same onClick event.

The method to handle these click events resides in the activity class that uses the layout. How do I set this method as the onClick handler for all child views?

Here is my code simplified.

The custom ViewGroup:

```
public class CellContainerGroup extends ViewGroup
{
    CellView[][] CellGrid = new CellView[9][9];

    public CellContainerGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.CellContainerGroup);

        try {
                //initialize attributes here.       
            } finally {
               a.recycle();
            }

        for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++)
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 9 ; j++)
            {
                //Add CellViews to CellGrid.
                CellGrid[i][j] = new CellView(context, null); //Attributeset passed as null
                //Manually set attributes, height, width etc.               
                //...

                //Add view to group
                this.addView(CellGrid[i][j], i*9 + j);
            }
    }
}
```

The activity that contains the method I want to use as the click handler:

```
public class SudokuGameActivity extends Activity {

    //Left out everything else from the activity.

    public void cellViewClicked(View view) {
    {
        //stuff to do here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a  single `OnClickListener`(in `CellContainerGroup`) which will call that method:

```
private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          CellContainerGroup ccg = (CellContainerGroup) v.getParent();
          ccg.propagateEvent(v);
     }
}
```

where `propagateEvent` is a method in `CellContainerGroup`  like this:

```
public void propagateEvent(View cell) {
     ((SudokuGameActivity)mContext).cellViewClicked(cell);
}
```

and where `mContext` is a `Context` reference like this:

```
private Context mContext;

public CellContainerGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   mContext = context;
//...
```

Don't forget to set the `mListener`:

```
CellGrid[i][j].setOnClickListener(mListener);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! I have only one problem though. When I try to click one of the cellviews, it always seems to click the upper right cell instead. Any idea what the reason for this could be?

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal I don't think that is related to the `OnCLickListener` at all, see if your cells are properly placed in the parent(so they aren't on top of each other).