# Custom button click event through Android-XML

Tags: android, android-button, android-custom-view

I've created a custom circular imagebutton in [GitHub](https://github.com/deathlord87/Android-Circular-ImageButton) I've my own clicklistener which is invoked onTouchEvent if the touch is on the circular bounds with the logic below

```
private void onTouchCircle(float x, float y, boolean up) {
    float cx = getWidth()/2;
    float cy = getHeight()/2;
    float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x - cx), 2) + Math.pow((y - cy), 2));
    float radius = getWidth()/2;
    if (distance < radius  && !up) {
        IS_PRESSED = true;
        getDrawable().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0X2E2E2E));
        invalidate();
    } else {
        IS_PRESSED = false;
        getDrawable().setColorFilter(null);

        if(distance<radius){
            BUTTON_PRESSED=true;
        }else{
            BUTTON_PRESSED=false;
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    if(up && BUTTON_PRESSED){
        BUTTON_PRESSED=false;
        Log.e(TAG, "distance -- "+distance+" -- radius --"+radius);
        if(onClickListener!=null){
            onClickListener.onCircularButtonClick(this);
        }
    }

}
```

How do I invoke the click to happen through XML like the android.widget.Button/android.widget.ImageButton? It would be great if I could invoke the method similar to button/imagebutton for my custom control like below. Any help is appreciated.

```
<com.example.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        xmlns:imaginea="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.circularimageview"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/breakdancing_android"
        imaginea:alpha="1"
        imaginea:onCircularButtonClick="myFancyMethod" />

public void myFancyMethod(View v) {
    // does something very interesting
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976774/set-individual-onclick-events-in-custom-viewgroup

Comment: yes I saw that. Note that the above is a View, also this view can be used by several viewgroups. I need to know exactly how the button onclick event works from xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how Android does it in their base [View.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L3565)

The key lines would be:

```
final String handlerName = a.getString(attr);
if (handlerName != null) {
    setOnCircularClickListener(new OnCircularClickListener() {
        private Method mHandler;

        public void onCircularButtonClick(View v) {
            if (mHandler == null) {
                try {
                    mHandler = getContext().getClass().getMethod(handlerName,
                            View.class);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    int id = getId();
                    String idText = id == NO_ID ? "" : " with id '"
                            + getContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                                id) + "'";
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find a method " +
                            handlerName + "(View) in the activity "
                            + getContext().getClass() + " for onClick handler"
                            + " on view " + CircularImageView.this.getClass() + idText, e);
                }
            }
            try {
                mHandler.invoke(getContext(), CircularImageView.this);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute non "
                        + "public method of the activity", e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute "
                        + "method of the activity", e);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: great lead..! now the problem lies with how do I invoke this with my own onClickEvent and make it work with android.View ??

Comment: I would rename your interface to `OnCircularClickListener` to differentiate from the builtin OnClickListener and create a setter for the member variable instead of making it public. Then change the above code to `setOnCircularClickListener(new OnCircularClickListener() { ... public void onCircularButtonClick(View v) {...` edited answer to reflect changes

Comment: mHandler.invoke(getContext(), View.this);
I am unable to get the context of View.this, should I call super().! I am getting method invocation error.

Comment: @LalithB Actually it should be `CircularImageView.this` since that's where this code is located. Edited answer to reflect.

Comment: both mean the same right ? "View v" will be an instance of CircularImageView